# What's the right way to store user temporary files in a digital ocean dropplet?

Tags: python, flask, digital-ocean, web-audio-api

I'm currently coding my web-app on an Ubuntu server hosted in a digital ocean dropplet.

My web app does the following:

1. **Receiving** input from the user via ajax
2. **Processing** audio files in server-side with Python
3. **Sending back** the processed audio file in client-side via ajax
4. **Played** by the user with the Web Audio API.

I was wondering, what's the best way to store the processed audio files (which will be there temporarly)? In my  server? in the user's browser?

For the moment, a file is overwritten in my server everytime a user is doing the task. But it will be a problem if multiple user does it simultaeously.

Does Anyone have an idea about the best practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what i do is create a `downloadables/` directory alongside my `app.py` and then save files to that directory. Then you can create more directories inside the `downloadables/` named user's unique identifier and save your audio files in those.
Here is a tree for demonstration purposes:

```
app.py
downloadables/
    └── 1
        └── file.wav
        └── file2.wav
    └── 2
        └── sound.mp3
```

Make sure to check for duplicate names while saving by using something like:

```py
import os
file=os.popen('find {} --name "*{}*"'.format(<user_uniqueid>, <input_filename>))
if file != '':
    #rename then save the file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arjun. So if 200 users process a file simultaeously, 200 files will be written on my server?

Comment: @DanShuri it should